# .htaccess 301 redirect for domain root level

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, google-analytics

I have written a php website, and used 301 redirects to redirect old urls in old website to new urls in new website.

The general presentation of the 301 redirect is like this:-

```
RewriteRule     ^chs/hong-kong/brand.php$   /cn/our-company? [L,R=301]
```

Even though there are more than 100 such rules, they works perfectly well.

In Google Analytics, when visitors visits a particular page I can observe the new urls in the statistics figures, except for root level of the domain `"/"`. In users' URL, no matter they use `http://sample.com`, or `http://sample.com/` , Google Analytics will not show `"/"`, but show `"/hello.php"`, while `hello.php` is not present in the new website, i.e., no such file.

After some research work, I found `hello.php` was the landing page of the old website.

I would like to understand, how I can rectify the /hello.php in Google Analytics. One of the possible way I can think of is, to create another 301 redirect like this:

```
RewriteRule     ^hello.php$ /en/home? [L,R=301]
```

Interestingly, the redirect works in the URL, but again, Google Analytics still show /hello.php

Would there be other better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend webmaster tools: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal?hl=en&siteUrl=http://www.example.com/